# Serre fibration and CW-complexes

Tags: homotopy-theory, cw-complexes, fibration

Suppose that $p:X\rightarrow E$ is a Serre fibration. I know the definition: then $p$ has the right lifting property with respect to all inclusions $I^n\rightarrow I^{n}\times I$. Now it seems that one can equivalently say that one has the right lifting property with respect to all CW-complexes. One implication is clear. But why is the from $I^n$ to CW-complexes correct. Comes this from the pushout construction of CW-complexes?

Comment: The other implication is not correct. A Serre fibration will only have the right lifting property with respect to cellular maps _which are (weak) homotopy equivalences_. A Serre fibration which has the right lifting property with respect to all cellular maps is in fact a weak homotopy equivalence. For example, the universal cover $\mathbb{R} \to S^1$ doesn't admit a lift of the identity map $S^1 \to S^1$. There's a lot more to say here...

Comment: @tcamps Okay thanks a lot :)